# visual studio 2005 .exe file not running on another computer

Tags: windows, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, exe

I have a visual studio 2005 c++ application running on a windows 7 64 bit machine.I tried to run it on another computer having windows 7 64 bit but when I copied it on to the desktop and runs the .exe file,there was no response.But I dont have the visual studio 2005 ide installed on the new machine and I am currently instaling it. Also, I googled and got lot of confusing answers. Can someone tell me what will be possible problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package" on the machine where the executable is not working.

Comment: @ShivShambo and there's no error message?  Are you statically linking the executable when you compile it?

Comment: @mrduclaw.. there is no error message..i am not sure the executable is static or dynamic exactly , the program is a old one written by other vendor 4 years back..

Answer (score 0):

You need to build for `Release` not `Debug` to run the application on a PC without Visual Studio. If you're already doing that, try loading the EXE into [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) on the target machine to see what other libraries might be missing.

Comment: ...I have got some warnings but the PC on which the program is working also have the same warnings... so dependency walker is not helping..